# How to define spark dataframe join match priority

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, join

I have two dataframes.

dataDF

```
+---+
| tt|
+---+
|  a|
|  b|
|  c|
| ab|
+---+
```

alter

```
+----+-----+------+
|name|alter|profit|
+----+-----+------+
|   a|   aa|     1|
|   b|    a|     5|
|   c|   ab|     8|
+----+-----+------+
```

The task is to search col "tt" in dataframe alter col("name"), if found it join them, if not found it, then search col "tt" in col("alter"). The priority of col ("name") is high than col("alter"). That means if row of col("tt") is matched to col("name"), I do not want to match it to other row which only matches col("alter"). How can I achieve this task?

I tried to write a join, but it does not work.

```
dataDF = dataDF.select("*")
      .join(broadcast(alterDF),
       col("tt") === col("Name") || col("tt") === col("alter"),
        "left")
```

The result is:

```
+---+----+-----+------+
| tt|name|alter|profit|
+---+----+-----+------+
|  a|   a|   aa|     1|
|  a|   b|    a|     5|   // this row is not expected. 
|  b|   b|    a|     5|
|  c|   c|   ab|     8|
| ab|   c|   ab|     8|
+---+----+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try joining twice. First time with the name column, filter out the tt values for which data is not matched and join it with the alter column. Union both the results. Please find the code below for the same. I hope it is helpful.

```
//Creating Test Data
val dataDF = Seq("a", "b", "c", "ab").toDF("tt")

val alter = Seq(("a", "aa", 1), ("b", "a", 5), ("c", "ab", 8))
    .toDF("name", "alter", "profit")

val join1 = dataDF.join(alter, col("tt") === col("name"), "left")

val join2 = join1.filter( col("name").isNull).select("tt")
  .join(alter, col("tt") === col("alter"), "left")

val joinDF = join1.filter( col("name").isNotNull).union(join2)

joinDF.show(false)

+---+----+-----+------+
|tt |name|alter|profit|
+---+----+-----+------+
|a  |a   |aa   |1     |
|b  |b   |a    |5     |
|c  |c   |ab   |8     |
|ab |c   |ab   |8     | 
+---+----+-----+------+
```